# Can Bromophenol Blue Sodium Salt, and Pentane be safely mixed/in contact with each other?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, safety

I'm trying to determine if powdered Bromophenol blue is safe to mix with Pentane. I would only need a tiny amount of dye, just enough to tint the pentane.
I need to use pentane for it's specific freezing point but I may be able to mix the pentane with another color indicators (wont be using this for PH, just need color)

Pentane
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sial/236705

Bromophenol Blue Sodium Salt - https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/bromophenol-blue-sodium-salt-fisher-bioreagents/BP11425

Comment: What make you think it's not safe to mix a dye with a hydrocarbon?

Comment: Safe yes. Immiscible - probably as the sodium salt is fairly polar I doubt you'll get much to go into the pentane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDS from the Fisher Scientific link you give lists only strong oxidizing agents as incompatible with your salt, so there is no safety issue with mixing the salt with the pentane apart from the flammability of said pentane.

Whether you get the solubility is a different matter. Salts usually don't go well with hydrocarbons, and the SDS does contain a line that this material is soluble in water (which makes solubility in the hydrocarbon even less likely).

A blue material that is more likely to work with pentane is [azulene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azulene).